# Bezeichnungen für grammatische Geschlechter

Tags: gender, terminology

Die deutsche Sprache hat drei grammatische Geschlechter. Die deutschen Bezeichnungen dafür sind:

- **männlich**
- **weiblich**
- **sächlich**

Alle drei Bezeichnungen sind Adjektive. Fachsprachlich sind dafür diese Bezeichnungen üblich:

- **Maskulinum**, abgeleitet von lateinisch »*masculum*« = »*männlich*«
- **Femininum** - »*femina*« = »*weiblich*«
- **Neutrum** - »*neutrum (ne-utrum)*« = »*keines von beiden*«

Das sind drei Substantive. Nun werden manchmal aber von den fachsprachlichen Nomen auch Adjektive abgeleitet:

- männlich - Maskulinum - **maskulin**
- weiblich - Femininum - **feminin**
- sächlich - Neutrum - **???** - *wie lautet das hier fehlende Adjektiv?*

In anderen Sprachen, z.B. in Schwedisch, gibt es ein weiteres grammatisches Geschlecht:

- **Utrum**, abgeleitet von lat. »*utrum*« = »*beides*«.

(Das Geschlecht *Utrum* ist eine Vereinigung von Maskulinum und Femininum, da im Schwedischen diese beiden »Geschlechter« grammatisch genau gleich behandelt werden. Schwedisch kennt zwei Geschlechter: Utrum und Neutrum.)

Alle indogermanischen und semitischen Sprachen kommen mit diesen vier grammatischen Geschlechtern aus, wovon aber keine dieser Sprachen mehr als drei verwendet. Die ganze Tabelle enthält also vier Zeilen, wovon ich aber nicht alle Positionen eindeutig besetzen kann. Was gehört an die fehlenden Stellen?

- männlich - Maskulinum - maskulin
- weiblich - Femininum - feminin
- sächlich - Neutrum - **???**
- **???** - Utrum - **???**

Comment: Randbemerkung: Das Tschechische hat ein „belebtes Maskulinum“ und ein „unbelebtes Maskulinum“, die sich unterschiedlich verhalten (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_declension#Adjective), also eigentlich vier Genera.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Laut Online-Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/neutral) heißt das Adjektiv zu *Neutrum* schlicht *neutral*. Zitat:

> 4. (Sprachwissenschaft) sächlich

In der deutschsprachigen Literatur werden dagegen, wie ich eben überrascht festgestellt habe, sehr häufig die Geschlechter als „maskulin, feminin, neutrum“ aufgezählt. Auch wenn das überhaupt nicht meinem Idiolekt entspricht, hab ich zunächst vermutet, dass das undeklinierbare Adjektiv *neutrum* bereits ein Wort der deutschen Sprache ist, das lediglich [dem Duden noch nicht bekannt ist](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/neutrum). Das wäre auch durchaus plausibel. Zunächst einmal gibt es drei einfache Arten, das Geschlecht eines Wortes mit einem Fremdwort anzugeben:

- *Mann* ist ein Maskulinum. *Mann* ist Maskulinum. *Mann* ist maskulin.
- *Frau* ist ein Femininum. *Frau* ist Femininum. *Frau* ist feminin.
- *Kind* ist ein Neutrum. *Kind* ist Neutrum. *Kind* ist neutral.

Aus für mich nicht ganz nachvollziehbaren Gründen, scheinen manche Leute, die kein Problem damit haben, *Busen* als maskulin und *Zeugungskraft* als feminin zu bezeichnen, Skrupel beim Adjektiv *neutral* für ein Genus zu haben. Jedenfalls wird das Substantiv *Neutrum* wohl schon seit langem deutlich häufiger als die beiden vergleichbaren Substantive ohne Artikel prädikativ verwendet:

- *Mann* ist maskulin, *Frau* ist feminin, *Kind* ist Neutrum.

Wie der Sprachwandel nun mal so funktioniert, kann durch die häufige prädikative Verwendung eines Substantivs ziemlich schnell ein nur prädikativ verwendbares und daher undeklinierbares Adjektiv entstehen.

Allerdings sind wir dann wohl doch noch nicht so weit. Im deutschsprachigen Google-Korpus gibt es [keinen einzigen Treffer für "ist neutrum"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ist+Neutrum%2Cist+neutrum&year_start=1800&corpus=20). Selbst wenn manche Sprecher vielleicht schon das undeklinierbare Adjektiv unbefangen benutzen, wird es wohl spätestens bei der Endredaktion einer Veröffentlichung groß geschrieben, also zu einem Substantiv korrigiert.

Die trotz Rechtschreibprüfung übliche Genus-Aufzählung „maskulin, feminin, neutrum“ dürfte also weit davon entfernt sein, anzuzeigen, dass das Adjektiv *neutrum* im Sprachgebrauch angekommen ist, sondern vielmehr den (oder einen) Vorläufer darstellen. Vermutlich ist diese Form der Aufzählung als etwas missglückte Modernisierung der klassischen lateinischen („masculinum, foemininum, neutrum“) entstanden. (PS: Die Eindeutschung erfolgt ja in solchen Fällen normalerweise durch Weglassen der Endung *-um*. Da das bei *neutrum* nicht geht – *neuter* funktioniert so nur im Englischen – muss man es unverändert lassen.) Ob sie zusammen mit dem vorher beschriebenen Effekt der adjektivischen Verwendung von *neutrum* zum Durchbruch verhelfen kann, ist noch abzuwarten. Dagegen spricht jedenfalls, dass mit *neutral* bereits ein vollständig deklinierbares Adjektiv zur Verfügung steht. Dagegen spricht auch, dass eine Steigerung des neuen Adjektivs *neutrum* abwegig ist. Damit scheint sein Weg in den offiziellen Sprachstandard im Wesentlichen verbaut zu sein.

---

Zu *Utrum* hab ich bisher noch kein deutsches Adjektiv gefunden. Jedenfalls ist das eigentlich zu erwartende *utral* im Deutschen definitiv nicht üblich. [Im schwedischen Wiktionary](https://sv.wiktionary.org/wiki/utral) existiert es dagegen. Da die Sprache lebt, hätte ich persönlich aber jedenfalls überhaupt kein Problem damit, das Adjektiv *utral* in einer linguistischen Veröffentlichung zu benutzen.

Answer (score 6):

Zunächst eine Anmerkung zur Sprachgeschichte: Eigentlich sind nicht die fachsprachlichen Adjektive von den Substantiven abgeleitet, sondern umgekehrt sind die Substantive substantivierte Adjektive; die antiken Grammatiker sprachen von *genus masculinum* („Männlich-Geschlecht“¹), *genus femininum* („Weiblich-Geschlecht“) und *genus neutrum* („keines der beiden Geschlechter“²). Der Begriff *genus utrum* („ein beliebiges der beiden Geschlechter“) ist nicht antik, sondern erst in jüngerer Zeit als Gegenstück zum *genus neutrum* geprägt worden, und wird nicht von allen als gelungene Prägung betracht. Eine häufig verwendete Alternative ist *genus commune* (gemeinsames Geschlecht), wobei allerdings auch die Gegenüberstellung Commune/Neutrum semantisch fragwürdig ist.

Nun zu den Lücken. Das etablierte Adjektiv zu *Neutrum* ist **neutral**, auch und gerade in dieser Bedeutung ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/neutral), [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/neutral)). *Utrum* ist, wie gesagt, relativ neu und wird im Deutschen selten verwendet, daher gibt es weder ein fachsprachlich-lateinstämmiges noch ein deutschstämmiges Adjektiv hierzu. In einem Text würde man vermutlich eine andere Formulierung mit dem Substantiv *Utrum* verwenden. Im Schwedischen allerdings wird gelegentlich [*utral*](https://sv.wiktionary.org/wiki/utral) benutzt; das wäre auch im Deutschen eine naheliegende Bildung, wenn man auf ein Adjektiv nicht verzichten kann.

---

¹ „Männliches Geschlecht” ist eigentlich keine richtige Wiedergabe, denn das wäre schon *genus masculum*; es steckt also noch eine weitere Ableitung darin. Das gilt entsprechend auch für das „weibliche Geschlecht”.

² Die lateinische Konstruktion, etwa „unbeides Geschlecht“, ist im Deutschen nicht nachzubilden.

Comment: Commune wird verwendet, wenn zwei Genera zusammenfallen. Das trifft zwar auf Maskulinum und Femininum in den meisten nordgermanischen Sprachen zu, aber noch üblicher ist der Begriff in den romanischen Sprachen, wo üblicherweise Maskulinum und Neutrum zunehmend nicht mehr unterschieden werden. In dem Begriff manifestiert sich eine diachrone Betrachtungsweise, die oft weniger hilfreich ist als eine konsequent synchrone.